# Laravel checkbox inside form won't check

Tags: forms, checkbox, laravel-5

I'm stuck in Laravel 5.2 trying to be able to interact with a checkbox inside a form.
When I click them, they just light up, but won't get checked.
It seems that when I remove the form tags (or blade tags), the checkboxes can be checked, but I need them to be inside a form to submit if checked or not...
code is located in home.blade.php in the @section('content')
This seems to work:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
        <li>
                <input id="item" name="id" onClick="this.form.submit" type="checkbox" value="{{ $item->id }}" {{ $item->done ? 'checked' : ''}} />
                {{ $item->name }}
        </li>
@endforeach
```

[Image of working checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx2lq.jpg)

But it fails here:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
        <li>
            {{Form::open()}}
                <input id="item" name="id" onClick="this.form.submit" type="checkbox" value="{{ $item->id }}" {{ $item->done ? 'checked' : ''}} />
                {{ $item->name }}
            {{Form::close()}}
        </li>
@endforeach
```

[Image checkboxes not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kNIk.jpg)

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `Form open` & `Form close` tag outside of `foreach`. It is creating many form as much as the foreach looped. Your code should look like this:

```
{{Form::open()}}
@foreach($items as $item)
    <ul>
        <li>       
            <input id="item" name="id" onClick="this.form.submit" type="checkbox" value="{{ $item->id }}" {{ $item->done ? 'checked' : ''}} />
            <label for="id">{{ $item->name }}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
@endforeach
{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: @Sharon Try wrap the `<li>` with `<ul>`

Comment: Nothing changed... I've edited my post by adding links to images of how it looks when working and when not working. It's really weird that the appearance is different, like it's not even a checkbox.

Comment: Try showing the `$item->name` as `label`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Check with the `Inspect Element` tools, is the checkbox is checked when the box light up? Or change the check/uncheck status in `Inspect Element` and see if the box is check or not?

Comment: I finally found the answer: It was in my css file. I forgot to delete the line "-webkit-appearance: none".
Thanks for all your effort! I really feel stupid...

Comment: Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are submitting the form as an onclick event of the checkbox. You are essentially submitting the form as soon as the checkbox is clicked, and since the form submits to itself, it is reloading in its default state (unchecked). By the time you have finished clicking it, the page has reloaded and it is unclicked again.

The reason why you don't see this when you remove the form tag, is because the event (submitting the form) no longer does anything, because there is no longer a form to submit.

I am referring to this offending attribute:

```
onClick="this.form.submit"
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. I already tried deleting this part, but nothing changed...

Comment: Are there other javascript onclick events defined on this checkbox element that aren't shown? If you are saying that when you click the checkbox, you don't see it change to a checked state (or see it briefly flicker to checked and then immediately change back), then there must be some javascript event on the field. I'm surprised, what I pointed out above would cause exactly that behavior.

Comment: Well, I don't see it being checked, just highlighted.
Also, the look of the checkbox looks more like a radiobutton, even though it's defined as a checkbox. And no, there are no other onclick events defined...